# Object is null after Post Request -- Angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, post

I have the following function in my angular project service file:

```
public saveReport(report: any): boolean {
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

this.http.post(url,
  report, {
    headers: headers
  }
).subscribe(
  (data) => {console.log(data);
  },
  error => console.log(error),
  () => { console.log('completed');
  }
);
return true;
}
```

I have a report that is being sent in through the UI and when I log it, the map shows its being populated both in my component and my service. But when I log it as the data (in the subscribe portion) I get null values. Once I hit Save those null values are being pushed to my cache overwriting my previous swagger test data.

Comment: Non-related, but setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is useless. These we set in the backend :)

Comment: the data in subscribe is the data from the server response

Comment: Is your server returning the object on the post? Maybe the problem is there? Can you use the developer tools or something like Postman to confirm that the server is returning the report after a post?

Comment: @Alex yeah I know that was kind of a last minute hail marry someone asked me to do haha and I found out its because I had to turn it back into an object and not a map in the backend! A quick function fixed it! thanks guys